# JMeter Constant Throughput Timer per thread?

Tags: timer, jmeter, constants, throughput

I am creating a JMeter test with 4 threads. Each thread has multiple Transaction controllers and between 45 and 98 HTTP requests.

Now the problem I have is that I want to add a constant throughput timer that will make sure that x amount of threads are done per minute. At the moment I need to specify the exact amount of HTTP requests and then it will do the thread in 1 minute. However I want it to start thread 1. Do it as fast as possible, then start it again on minute 2, and so on and so forth.

Can this be done with the Constant Throughput Timer or do I need to use an alternative?

Thanks in advance.
-Blacksoil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constant Throughput Timer will be enough for your scenario. Despite word "Constant" in its name it doesn't have to be constant, you can put a JMeter Property in the "Throughput" input field and change it on the fly. See [How to use JMeter's Throughput Constant Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) guide for more details.

By the way, there is an extended version of the CTT - [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) which provides more flexible throughput control options and even visual representation of the throughput on test scenario timeline:

[image]